# Python calling shell commands. What type of shell is started?

Tags: python, shell

I have the following python function that allows me to run shell commands from within a python script:

```
import subprocess   

def run_shell_command(cmd,cwd=None):
      retVal = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=cwd);
      retVal = retVal.stdout.read().strip('\n');
      return(retVal);
```

This allows me to do things like:

```
output = run_shell_command("echo 'Hello world'")
```

My question is: with the definition of `run_shell_command` above, which type of shell is started? (e.g. [login vs  interactive](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html)).

Knowing which shell is started would help know which which `dot` files (e.g. `.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc.) are executed prior to my shell command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What shell is run?

This is mentioned in the [Python `subprocess` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

> The executable argument specifies the program to execute. It is very seldom needed: Usually, the program to execute is defined by the args argument. If shell=True, the executable argument specifies which shell to use. **On Unix, the default shell is `/bin/sh`**. On Windows, the default shell is specified by the `COMSPEC` environment variable. The only reason you would need to specify `shell=True` on Windows is where the command you wish to execute is actually built in to the shell, eg dir, copy. You don’t need shell=True to run a batch file, nor to run a console-based executable.

`/bin/sh` on Linux/MacOSX is typically an alias for bash (or bash-compatible - newer versions of Debian use dash), whereas on Unixes like Solaris, it might be classic Bourne Shell.

For Windows, it's usually `cmd` or `command.bat`.

### Login shell or not via `popen`?

I just realized that I haven't answered your 2nd question - but setting `shell=True` will spawn a non-login shell (look @AndiDog's source code link, the way the shell is getting forked would create a non-login shell).

---

### Security Implications

Also be aware that using `shell=True`, while it allows you to use shell primitives and shortcuts, can [also be a security risk](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments), so be sure to check any possible inputs you might use for process spawning.

> Warning Executing shell commands that incorporate unsanitized input from an untrusted source makes a program vulnerable to shell injection, a serious security flaw which can result in arbitrary command execution. For this reason, the use of shell=True is strongly discouraged in cases where the command string is constructed from external input:

```
>>>
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> filename = input("What file would you like to display?\n")
What file would you like to display?
non_existent; rm -rf / #
>>> call("cat " + filename, shell=True) # Uh-oh. This will end badly...
```

> `shell=False` disables all shell based features, but does not suffer from this vulnerability; see the Note in the Popen constructor documentation for helpful hints in getting shell=False to work.

Answer (score 8):

It's `/bin/sh` on POSIX. See the [source code `subprocess.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d21aa21f2cbc6d50aab3f420bb23be1d081dac4/Lib/subprocess.py#L914) (quoting Python 2.7 here):

```
def _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
                   cwd, env, universal_newlines,
                   startupinfo, creationflags, shell, to_close,
                   p2cread, p2cwrite,
                   c2pread, c2pwrite,
                   errread, errwrite):
    """Execute program (POSIX version)"""

    if isinstance(args, types.StringTypes):
        args = [args]
    else:
        args = list(args)

    if shell:
        args = ["/bin/sh", "-c"] + args
        if executable:
            args[0] = executable
    [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a login shell, so you don't get .login etc.

If for any reason you *need* to initialize a shell that thinks it's a login shell, you'll need to execute the shell yourself and (I believe this is still how this is done) change the first character of the argv[0] it sees to be a "-".